# Android emulator is online, but I can't control it

Tags: android, android-emulator

My emulator is online, adb is seeing it, but emulator itself can't get through the startup to homescreen. Startup routine stops when the title ANDROID is on the screen. I thought that the key to repaired emulator is update to the newest version of android sdk, but it wasn't worked. It is still the same problem.
Thanks

```
12-31 15:47:32.269: I/DEBUG(30): debuggerd: Jun 30 2010 14:39:19
12-31 15:47:33.351: D/qemud(37): entering main loop
12-31 15:47:33.359: I/Netd(29): Netd 1.0 starting
12-31 15:47:33.669: I/Vold(28): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
12-31 15:47:34.109: D/Vold(28): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
12-31 15:47:37.309: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
12-31 15:47:37.339: D/qemud(37): created client 0xe078 listening on fd 8
12-31 15:47:37.369: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 8
12-31 15:47:38.279: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
12-31 15:47:38.279: D/qemud(37): created client 0xf028 listening on fd 8
12-31 15:47:38.323: D/qemud(37): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'gsm'
12-31 15:47:38.359: D/qemud(37): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 1
12-31 15:47:38.609: D/qemud(37): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 1
12-31 15:47:41.589: W/Vold(28): No UMS switch available
12-31 15:47:43.260: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
12-31 15:47:43.269: D/qemud(37): created client 0x10fd8 listening on fd 11
12-31 15:47:43.269: D/qemud(37): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'boot-properties'
12-31 15:47:43.269: D/qemud(37): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 2
12-31 15:47:43.319: D/qemud(37): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 2
12-31 15:47:43.319: I/qemu-props(53): connected to 'boot-properties' qemud service.
12-31 15:47:43.427: I/qemu-props(53): received: dalvik.vm.heapsize=24m
12-31 15:47:43.512: I/qemu-props(53): received: qemu.sf.lcd_density=240
12-31 15:47:43.519: I/qemu-props(53): received: qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
12-31 15:47:43.539: I/qemu-props(53): received: qemu.sf.fake_camera=back
12-31 15:47:43.549: I/qemu-props(53): received: 
12-31 15:47:43.549: I/qemu-props(53): invalid format, ignored.
12-31 15:47:56.878: D/AndroidRuntime(32): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
12-31 15:47:57.021: D/AndroidRuntime(32): CheckJNI is ON
12-31 15:48:08.499: D/AndroidRuntime(32): --- registering native functions ---
12-31 15:48:09.228: I/(33): ServiceManager: 0xacd0
12-31 15:48:09.348: D/AudioHardwareInterface(33): setMode(NORMAL)
12-31 15:48:09.656: I/CameraService(33): CameraService started: pid=33
12-31 15:48:10.091: I/AudioFlinger(33): AudioFlinger's thread 0xb3a0 ready to run
12-31 15:48:18.638: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(32): Profiler is disabled.
12-31 15:48:19.748: I/Zygote(32): Preloading classes...
12-31 15:48:19.809: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
12-31 15:48:20.058: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 821 objects / 47480 bytes in 200ms
12-31 15:48:25.799: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 219 objects / 13600 bytes in 85ms
12-31 15:48:27.409: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 253 objects / 14344 bytes in 116ms
12-31 15:48:28.942: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 466 objects / 28864 bytes in 132ms
12-31 15:48:35.090: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2090 objects / 108328 bytes in 149ms
12-31 15:48:38.822: W/MediaProfiles(32): could not find media config xml file
12-31 15:48:39.334: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 279 objects / 15984 bytes in 174ms
12-31 15:48:46.259: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5012 objects / 223152 bytes in 343ms
12-31 15:49:03.428: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11282 objects / 381088 bytes in 405ms
12-31 15:49:09.639: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9805 objects / 461888 bytes in 481ms
12-31 15:49:16.128: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8694 objects / 422936 bytes in 597ms
12-31 15:49:24.338: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7648 objects / 458560 bytes in 495ms
12-31 15:49:31.609: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7537 objects / 458192 bytes in 542ms
12-31 15:49:39.671: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7189 objects / 457624 bytes in 641ms
12-31 15:49:49.369: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8598 objects / 513456 bytes in 665ms
12-31 15:49:51.139: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 453 objects / 39176 bytes in 503ms
12-31 15:49:54.469: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 594 objects / 29016 bytes in 516ms
12-31 15:49:55.903: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 449 objects / 25096 bytes in 543ms
12-31 15:50:00.578: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 308 objects / 35136 bytes in 737ms
12-31 15:50:03.119: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 279 objects / 18952 bytes in 721ms
12-31 15:50:08.969: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 341 objects / 18432 bytes in 760ms
12-31 15:50:13.078: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 449 objects / 28248 bytes in 776ms
12-31 15:50:42.519: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 528 objects / 53056 bytes in 834ms
12-31 15:50:44.628: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 623 objects / 34024 bytes in 925ms
12-31 15:50:46.749: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 861 objects / 46840 bytes in 753ms
12-31 15:50:49.958: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1747 objects / 85576 bytes in 848ms
12-31 15:50:52.008: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 447 objects / 29448 bytes in 1000ms
12-31 15:50:54.098: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 315 objects / 20120 bytes in 1087ms
12-31 15:50:54.399: I/Zygote(32): ...preloaded 1265 classes in 154643ms.
12-31 15:50:54.419: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
12-31 15:50:55.511: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 104 objects / 14216 bytes in 1092ms
12-31 15:50:58.119: I/Zygote(32): Preloading resources...
12-31 15:50:58.451: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080093 (res/drawable-hdpi/sym_def_app_icon.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:50:58.590: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080002 (res/drawable-hdpi/arrow_down_float.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:50:59.389: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b3 (res/drawable/btn_check.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:50:59.528: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b6 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_label_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:50:59.588: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800b7 (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_off.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:50:59.588: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10800bc (res/drawable-hdpi/btn_check_on.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:50:59.990: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080004 (res/drawable/btn_default.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:00.350: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080005 (res/drawable/btn_default_small.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:00.729: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080006 (res/drawable/btn_dropdown.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:01.074: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080008 (res/drawable/btn_plus.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:01.409: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080007 (res/drawable/btn_minus.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:01.839: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080009 (res/drawable/btn_radio.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:02.552: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108000a (res/drawable/btn_star.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:03.469: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 421 objects / 25888 bytes in 916ms
12-31 15:51:03.759: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080131 (res/drawable/btn_toggle.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:03.869: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080194 (res/drawable-hdpi/ic_emergency.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:03.948: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080012 (res/drawable-hdpi/divider_horizontal_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:04.031: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080014 (res/drawable-hdpi/divider_horizontal_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:04.419: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080016 (res/drawable/edit_text.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:04.618: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108016d (res/drawable/expander_group.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:05.006: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080062 (res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:05.099: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080227 (res/drawable-hdpi/menu_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:05.209: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080228 (res/drawable-hdpi/menu_background_fill_parent_width.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:05.522: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080229 (res/drawable/menu_selector.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:05.609: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080234 (res/drawable-hdpi/panel_background.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:05.699: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023b (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_bottom_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:05.779: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023c (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_bottom_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:05.889: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023d (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:05.979: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023e (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_center_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:06.089: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108023f (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_center_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:06.179: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080242 (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_full_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:06.269: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080245 (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_top_bright.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:06.369: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080246 (res/drawable-hdpi/popup_top_dark.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:06.760: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108006d (res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:06.879: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108024c (res/drawable/progress_small.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:07.014: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108024d (res/drawable/progress_small_titlebar.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:07.130: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080270 (res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_horizontal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:07.219: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080271 (res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:08.209: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 477 objects / 32640 bytes in 987ms
12-31 15:51:08.489: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080071 (res/drawable/spinner_dropdown_background.xml) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:08.699: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080354 (res/drawable-hdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:08.779: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d6 (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_drag_direction_green_up.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:08.890: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d7 (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_drag_direction_red_up.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:08.989: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d8 (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_default.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:09.099: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801d9 (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_green.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:09.219: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801da (res/drawable-hdpi/indicator_code_lock_point_area_red.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:09.328: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801e8 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_confirm_gray.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:09.419: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801ec (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:09.539: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801ed (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:09.629: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f1 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_confirm_gray.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:09.729: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f5 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:09.837: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f6 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:09.929: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801fb (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_left_confirm_gray.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:10.039: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080200 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_left_normal.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:10.139: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080201 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_left_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:10.249: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080203 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_right_confirm_gray.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:10.355: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080209 (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_right_normal.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:10.449: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108020a (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_right_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:10.558: W/Zygote(32): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108020d (res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_target_gray.png) that varies with configuration!!
12-31 15:51:10.568: I/Zygote(32): ...preloaded 61 resources in 12448ms.
12-31 15:51:11.074: I/Zygote(32): ...preloaded 15 resources in 488ms.
12-31 15:51:11.999: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 505 objects / 37936 bytes in 922ms
12-31 15:51:12.958: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 150 objects / 5792 bytes in 844ms
12-31 15:51:13.968: D/dalvikvm(32): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2 objects / 48 bytes in 986ms
12-31 15:51:14.269: I/dalvikvm(32): System server process 68 has been created
12-31 15:51:14.509: I/Zygote(32): Accepting command socket connections
12-31 15:51:20.894: E/BatteryService(68): usbOnlinePath not found
12-31 15:51:20.899: E/BatteryService(68): batteryVoltagePath not found
12-31 15:51:20.921: E/BatteryService(68): batteryTemperaturePath not found
12-31 15:51:21.139: I/sysproc(68): Entered system_init()
12-31 15:51:21.189: I/sysproc(68): ServiceManager: 0x11ff88
12-31 15:51:21.297: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): SurfaceFlinger is starting
12-31 15:51:21.339: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
12-31 15:51:21.439: E/SurfaceFlinger(68): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): using (fd=25)
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): id           = 
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): xres         = 480 px
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): yres         = 800 px
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): xres_virtual = 480 px
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): yres_virtual = 1600 px
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): bpp          = 16
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): r            = 11:5
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): g            =  5:6
12-31 15:51:21.929: I/gralloc(68): b            =  0:5
12-31 15:51:21.987: I/gralloc(68): width        = 74 mm (164.756760 dpi)
12-31 15:51:21.987: I/gralloc(68): height       = 123 mm (165.203247 dpi)
12-31 15:51:21.987: I/gralloc(68): refresh rate = 60.00 Hz
12-31 15:51:22.340: D/libEGL(68): egl.cfg not found, using default config
12-31 15:51:22.459: D/libEGL(68): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
12-31 15:51:22.808: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): EGL informations:
12-31 15:51:22.808: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): # of configs : 8
12-31 15:51:22.839: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): vendor    : Android
12-31 15:51:22.839: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
12-31 15:51:22.849: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): extensions: EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_image_pixmap EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer EGL_ANDROID_swap_rectangle EGL_ANDROID_get_render_buffer 
12-31 15:51:22.849: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): Client API: OpenGL ES
12-31 15:51:22.849: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): EGLSurface: 5-6-5-0, config=0x1000000
12-31 15:51:22.869: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): flags     : 001c0000
12-31 15:51:23.009: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): OpenGL informations:
12-31 15:51:23.009: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): vendor    : Android
12-31 15:51:23.009: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): renderer  : Android PixelFlinger 1.3
12-31 15:51:23.009: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): version   : OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
12-31 15:51:23.009: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): extensions: GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap 
12-31 15:51:23.033: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096
12-31 15:51:23.033: I/SurfaceFlinger(68): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096
12-31 15:51:23.218: I/sysproc(68): System server: starting Android runtime.
12-31 15:51:23.218: I/sysproc(68): System server: starting Android services.
12-31 15:51:23.440: I/SystemServer(68): Entered the Android system server!
12-31 15:51:23.568: I/sysproc(68): System server: entering thread pool.
12-31 15:51:23.740: I/SystemServer(68): Entropy Service
12-31 15:51:25.278: I/SystemServer(68): Power Manager
12-31 15:51:25.948: I/SystemServer(68): Activity Manager
12-31 15:51:26.998: I/ActivityManager(68): Memory class: 24
12-31 15:51:28.419: D/libEGL(77): egl.cfg not found, using default config
12-31 15:51:28.593: D/libEGL(77): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
12-31 15:51:29.258: W/zipro(77): Unable to open zip '/data/local/bootanimation.zip': No such file or directory
12-31 15:51:29.258: W/zipro(77): Unable to open zip '/system/media/bootanimation.zip': No such file or directory
12-31 15:51:32.468: I/UsageStats(68): Deleting usage file : usage-20111026
12-31 15:51:33.428: I/ARMAssembler(68): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00000004_00000000 [ 22 ipp] (41 ins) at [0x231748:0x2317ec] in 113143335 ns
12-31 15:51:34.958: I/ARMAssembler(77): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000A01_00000000 [ 30 ipp] (51 ins) at [0x1c378:0x1c444] in 103565037 ns
12-31 15:51:48.388: I/SystemServer(68): Telephony Registry
12-31 15:51:48.788: I/SystemServer(68): Package Manager
12-31 15:51:49.988: I/Installer(68): connecting...
12-31 15:51:50.108: I/installd(34): new connection
12-31 15:51:55.859: I/PackageManager(68): Libs: android.test.runner:/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar javax.obex:/system/framework/javax.obex.jar com.google.android.maps:/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar
12-31 15:51:55.940: I/PackageManager(68): Features: android.hardware.camera android.hardware.camera.autofocus
12-31 15:52:07.636: D/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4857 objects / 217936 bytes in 4377ms
```

This is my latest log from my logcat. I've got even an error now

Comment: There will be some information in logcat. That may give some clues.

Comment: no, nothing useful about that, I checked all

Comment: after a few startups and experimenting i got error: 
Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2

Comment: Anyone has an answer?? Please

Comment: I would suggest uninstall and reinstall everything. It seems during upgrade something messedup.

Answer (score 0):

It also happends with me.
It happends perhaps if you have close th adb during any important process is occuring on it or may be any service is running on it.
Anyway, Deleting that adb and creating new one solved my problem. So please make new adb and use it for application development and testing.

Enjoy.

Comment: Hello. Do you mean AVD instead of adb? I make plenty of new virtual devices and all have the same problems

Comment: Yes its my Mistake.i mean AVD only.

Comment: If you still seen this type of error then try to update the Eclipse and sdk as well.

Comment: I updated sdk, tools, plug-ins... everything, but something is just not right. I forgot to mention that developing with phone is going perfectly normal, only problem is with virtual devices

Comment: Do you have created AVD  with commend prompt or with the start already created avd from the Android Sdk Avd Manager ???

Comment: If you have already created AVD and starting it then put the configuration you have put for it.

Comment: I have tried so many configuration that I can not count them all. I tried with every possible configuration. Emulator don't work even if I choose just sdk version and name.

Comment: Could please someone give me a hint. After several reinstalling sdk and everything, I still can't work with emulator. :((